# Как вывести в консоль названия текстовых файлов в папке? с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Работаю с библиотекой fstream. Создаю файлы в папке, а как вывести их названия в консоли, не могу понять. Названия всех файлов.txt сразу и чтоб потом при удалении одного файла, он больше не отображался в консоли. Прошу помочь

Comment: непонятная какая-то задача или вы ее так описали - а чем `std::cout <<` не устраивает?

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли. У меня есть папка с текстовыми файлами. Каждый файл имеет свою определенную информацию. Я хотел бы, чтоб названия этих файлов в папке, отображались в консоль.

Comment: т.е. ваша задача найти все файлы в заданной папке и вывести это на экран?

Comment: Да. Именно так. Их названия просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на чистом c++ (правда c++17):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

std::string path = "путь к папке";
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
```

что конкретно вывести о файле посмотрите тут:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry

если хотите получить не путь к файлу, а только имя, то:

для имени файла: `.filename()`

для голого имени: `.stem()`

для расширения: `.extension()`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @ДавидШамсани, потому что нужно включить C++17, и использовать компилятор не меньше, чем g++-9 и  clang-9. До этого много проблем было.

Comment: @ДавидШамсани, или msvc 2017.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, очень помогли. Вы первый человек за 3 дня, с помощью которого я смог решить проблему!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using std::string_literals;

for (const auto& dir_entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{"path/to/dir"})
    if (dir_entry.path().extension().string() == ".txt"s)
        std::cout << dir_entry.path().filename() << std::endl;
```